# C++ Setting member object which has const member

Tags: c++, constants, ogre

I am using OIS for handling my input with Ogre and currently, on KeyPress/Release a Message object like the following will be constructed and distributed among subscribers.

```
class Message
{
public:
    Message();
    ~Message();

    inline void SetKeyEvent(const OIS::KeyEvent& keyEvent) { _keyEvent = keyEvent; }

    const OIS::KeyEvent& GetKeyEvent() const { return _keyEvent; }

private:

    OIS::KeyEvent _keyEvent;

};
```

Since this object will be constructed/destroyed whenever input is received via keyboard, I am trying to store a pre-constructed Message object and then simply update the `_keyEvent` field with the new data, before distributing.

The problem is that the `OIS::KeyEvent` object has a const member which is preventing me from using the assignment operator. The SetKeyEvent method gives me the following syntax error:

```
function "OIS::KeyEvent::operator=(const OIS::KeyEvent &)" (declared implicitly) cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function
```

I was wondering what the best way to achieve this functionality would be?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Just to clarify, I already use initializer lists when possible. My intention is to have the Message object pre-constructed and then update the `_keyEvent` field with the new event data from the KeyPress event which OIS fires, using the `SetKeyEvent` method. I would like to know if this is possible and if so, what the best way to do it would be.

Comment: It's not about a const member. It means `OIS::KeyEvent` has no assignment operator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why should I prefer to use member initialization list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926752/why-should-i-prefer-to-use-member-initialization-list)

Comment: @Hayt it has no default assignment operator *because* there's a const member in it.

Comment: you're right. I totally did not make that connection somehow.

Comment: Do you really need to store a pre-constructed message? Does it have other members?

Comment: @n.m. I could allocate new Message objects, i was wanting to have them pre-constructed to avoid allocating a new message object every time a key is pressed/released

Comment: You mean, you have to allocate one from the free store? Why? Can you use an automatic variable, or maybe pass messages by value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The copy operator is deleted, so you must work with pointers.

```
class Message
{
public:
    Message();
    ~Message();

    inline void SetKeyEvent(OIS::KeyEvent* keyEvent) { _keyEvent = keyEvent; }

    const OIS::KeyEvent& GetKeyEvent() const { return _keyEvent; }

private:

    OIS::KeyEvent* _keyEvent;

};
```

And now it's better to check if the argument in the setter isn't nullptr.

```
inline void SetKeyEvent(OIS::KeyEvent* keyEvent) 
{
   assert(keyEvent != nullptr);
   _keyEvent = keyEvent; 
}
```

`assert()` needs `#include <assert.h>`

EDIT:

Sorry, forgot the getter method. You must use pointers, too.

```
const OIS::KeyEvent* keyEvent = &Message.GetKeyEvent();
```

Where `Message` is your class instance.

Comment: Don't do this. Use the constructor [correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926752/why-should-i-prefer-to-use-member-initialization-list), that's all.

Comment: The error message throws when the getter was called and there is no constructor call.

Comment: What error message? If you have a question about the getter, ask it.

Comment: There is a error message in the question:  function "OIS::KeyEvent::operator=(const OIS::KeyEvent &)" (declared implicitly) cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function

Comment: You fix it by not using assignment. Note the getter returns by reference.

Comment: Yes, because the assignment operator in OIS::KeyEvent is deleted and he can't use it.

Comment: Marked as answer - using the pointer route, i adjusted my implementation which allowed me to pre-construct my objects and set the new `OIS::KeyEvent` data via pointer

Answer (score -1):

It is possible by using placement new and an explicit destructor call, things you normally should never do:

```
 inline void SetKeyEvent(const OIS::KeyEvent& keyEvent) 
 { 
     _keyEvent.~KeyEvent();
     new (&_keyEvent) OIS::KeyEvent(keyEvent);
 }
```

This is bad ugly horrible code, use at your own risk.